# NodeJS array result empty when push

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am try to push data of my database into array but here I got little problem, when I try to `console.log` it's showing empty.

Here is my code :

```
var arrTodo     =[];
conn.query(todoq,function(err, rows, fields) {
    rows.forEach(function(detail){
        arrTodo.push(detail.name);
    });
});
console.log(arrTodo);
```

Anyone can help me put ?

Comment: Is `conn.query` asynchronous?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697)

Comment: I guess `conn.query` is the asynchronous function. If you want to log the result, move `console.log` into `forEach` scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as mentioned in comments, `conn.query` is asynchronous. so the callback you provide, is called at sometime later on while you've already console logged it.

You can use a promise to fix your problem:

```
function getQuery() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        conn.query(todoq,function(err, rows, fields) {
            var arrTodo = [];

            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            rows.forEach(function(detail){
                arrTodo.push(detail.name);
            });

            return resolve(arrTodo);
        });
    });
}

getQuery().then(arrTodo => console.log(arrTodo)).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Also, you could improve your code a bit using `arr.map` method, like this:

```
function getQuery() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        conn.query(todoq,function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            let arrTodo = rows.map(function(detail){
                return detail.name;
            });

            return resolve(arrTodo);
        });
    });
}

getQuery().then(arrTodo => console.log(arrTodo)).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

With promises, you can also use async-await:

```
(
    async function () {
        let arrTodo = await getQuery();
        console.log(arrTodo);
    }
)()
```

Comment: The original question was a "Javascript 101 for newbies" kind of question (a duplicate of a question whose response has 5047 upvotes), but your reply was helpful for pointing out the potential for using [Promises](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies), [Async maps](https://medium.com/@ian.mundy/async-map-in-javascript-b19439f0099) and [Async await](https://javascript.info/async-await).  Good job!

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

```
var arrTodo     =[];
conn.query(todoq,function(err, rows, fields) {
    rows.forEach(function(detail){
        arrTodo.push(detail.name);
    });
    console.log(arrTodo);
});
```

Comment: You have to explain why your changes will help. And what the problem is.